# How to have two different gateways on two different bridges in Proxmox VE

Tags: linux, networking, bridge, gateway, proxmox

We have two different network interfaces `eno1` and `eno2` (`eno3` and `eno4` are not connected) and we have one bridge `vmbr0` we want to add another bridge `vmbr1` and we want to set two different gateways  on these bridges.

Currently `vmbr0`'s gateway is set to `172.20.10.1`.
now we want to create another bridge `vmbr1` and set it's gateway to `172.20.1.40`

I entered these parameters for creating `vmbr1` [image]

but the proxmox interface doesn't allow this [image: proxmox's error]

This is my configuration [image: config]

and [this](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/h4wRFb5QjT/) is the output of `ifconfig`.

I am using Proxmox VE 5.4-13 on 
HP ProLiant DL380p Gen8

and `uname -a` shows

`Linux vmserver1 4.15.18-21-pve #1 SMP PVE 4.15.18-48 (Fri, 20 Sep 2019 11:28:30 +0200) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

The main reason I want to do this is for creating VMs on two different networks.

**The networks are separate and NOT PHYSICALLY CONNECTED to each other.**

Comment: I want to have VMs on two different networks.

Comment: There are two different networks both local the `172.20.10.0/24` (`vmbr0`) range has internet. so you mean I should add `vmbr1` with no gateway and assign it to VMs?

Comment: I tried it the VM can't connect to anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing the network routing table for the host with the definition of a bridge. A bridge does not have a default route; it's just a device for connecting different network interfaces. Routing tables can have a default route (or not).

When you define a bridge you also get the opportunity to define a default route *for a host interface* through that bridge, but you do not need to assign either a host IP address or default route.

In your case you say, "*Currently `vmbr0`'s gateway is set to `172.20.10.1`. now we want to create another bridge `vmbr1` and set its gateway to `172.20.1.40`*". You can't do that: a server can have just a single default gateway<sup>*</sup>, which *by definition* defines the route for packets that have no other explicit destination.

However, your virtual machines can have a default route, and they could have an IP address on the subnet you've planned for `vmbr1` (172.20.1.0/24, perhaps?), and an associated default route of `172.20.1.40`.

An example. On my home network I also have two NICs each attached to a bridge. The host itself has an IP address only on one of these bridges. A firewall has an IP address on both bridges, and the remainder of my VMs are attached to just one bridge.

DO NOT plan for your Proxmox host to route between the two networks. It won't do that by default and it would be a very bad idea to make it do so.

<sub>* Unless you choose the complexity of multiple routing tables, but let's not go there.</sub>

Comment: What are the reasons *why* having the Proxmox host route between the two networks is a bad idea (other than that it's not the default behavior)?

Comment: @cpit Proxmox is a hypervisor. Let it do that one thing well. If you want a router between two networks you should use a specialised device or if that's not possible then set it up in a VM

Comment: Gotcha. Then if you had, for example, a Proxmox host with multiple NICs on separate, otherwise unconnected, networks, it would be reasonable to route between them given that functionality was isolated to a container? And so it would be the isolation that made such a setup not as much of a "very bad idea"?

Comment: @cpit I would say so, yes